# How to use 'refresh_token' in IdentityServer 4?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I'm using .net core with IdentityServer 4. I have a Web api, and an MVC app which accesses secure endpoints on the api. It's very similar in setup to the IdentityServer quickstart:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity

I'm finding that my `access_tokens` are expiring, and I'd like to understand how to renegotiate `refresh_tokens`.

Take the following code for example (taken from the quickstart [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src/MvcClient/Controllers/HomeController.cs)):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CallApiUsingUserAccessToken()
    {
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
        var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5001/identity");

        ViewBag.Json = JArray.Parse(content).ToString();
        return View("json");
    }
```

If the `access_token` has expired, it will fail with 401 response. Is there a built-in mechanism for re-negotiating the `access_token` using the `refresh_token`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is not a build in system to refresh the `access_token`. However you can use the `IdentityModel` package to request a new `access_token` with a `refresh_token`.

The `Client` has a property `AllowOfflineAccess` which you should set to true in the IdentityServer. Note that this does **not** work for the implicit/client credentials flow.

- Always refresh the access_token prior to making the call to the protected resource
- Check if the current `access_token` is about to expire by checking its lifetime and request a new `access_token` with the `refresh_token` (personal preference)
- Wait for the API to return the 401 and request a new `access_token` with the `refresh_token`

Prior to this code you can check the `access_token` lifetime and/or wrap this code in a service before you request a new `access_token`

```cs
    var discoveryResponse = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("IdentityServer url");
    if (discoveryResponse.IsError)
    {
        throw new Exception(discoveryResponse.Error);
    }
    
    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(discoveryResponse.TokenEndpoint, "ClientId", "ClientSecret");
    // This will request a new access_token and a new refresh token.
    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(await httpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token"));
    
    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
    {
        // Handle error.
    }
    
    var oldIdToken = await httpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
    
    var tokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>
    {
        new AuthenticationToken
        {
            Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken,
            Value = oldIdToken
        },
        new AuthenticationToken
        {
            Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken,
            Value = tokenResult.AccessToken
        },
        new AuthenticationToken
        {
            Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken,
            Value = tokenResult.RefreshToken
        }
    };
    
    var expiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(tokenResult.ExpiresIn);
    tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken
    {
        Name = "expires_at",
        Value = expiresAt.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    });
    
    // Sign in the user with a new refresh_token and new access_token.
    var info = await httpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync("Cookies");
    info.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);
    await httpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookies", info.Principal, info.Properties);
```

Taken from and slightly modified: [Source](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/293622b8438d27f4c9c2574e43fe92a22560ac6b/Clients/src/MvcHybrid/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L46%20)

Comment: "Always refresh the access_token prior to making the call to the protected resource" - this is not always necessary and kinda defeats one of the points of refresh-tokens (that is, to reduce the burden on authentication servers) by eliminating the need for every request to be re-authenticated.

Comment: TokenClient is obsolete, could you have an example with the new method?

Comment: @JuanPablo Now you could use like that `var response = await client.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest
    {
     Address = discoveryResponse.TokenEndpoint,

     ClientId = "mvc",
     ClientSecret = "secret",
     Scope = "my api",

     RefreshToken = refreshToken
   });`

Comment: And you also can find the discovery with the HttpClient `var discoveryResponse = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("http://localhost:5500");`

Comment: For anyone wondering how to get the actual refresh token, when you first authenticate, you need to add `offline_access` to your scopes when you make the request.  When you do that, the refresh_token will come back along with the `access_token`, `expires_in`, and `token_type`.

Comment: @EricGarrison That was exactly what I was desperately looking for. Thatswhy +1

Comment: I'm using "hybrid" grant type and when I make this call with Scope = "myapi offline_access", I'm getting an error returned "invalid_grant".  I have myapi and offline_access as scopes for my clientId and AllowOfflineAccess = true in identity.

Comment: @EricGarrison: it has to be `expires_at` instead of `expires_in`