# IdentityServer4 Access token updating

Tags: access-token, identityserver4, refresh-token

Last week I am trying to configure the IdentityServer4 to get an access token automatically updating.

I had an API:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5100";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = "api1";  
            });
```

My MVC client configuration:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5100";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("api1");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            });
```

And the IdentityServer's clients configuration:

```
return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientName = "My mvc",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,

                RequireConsent = false,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 10,
                
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris           = { "http://localhost:5102/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5102/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                    "api1"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }

        };
```

On the client side I use AJAX queries to call the API to get/post/put/delete data. I add the access token to the request and get the result.

```
private async getAuthenticationHeader(): Promise<any> {
    return axios.get('/token').then((response: any) => {
        return { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${response.data}` } };
    });
}

async getAsync<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
    return this.httpClient
        .get(url, await this.getAuthenticationHeader())
        .then((response: any) => response.data as T)
        .catch((err: Error) => {
            console.error(err);
            throw err;
        });
}
```

The access token is provided by the MVC client method:

```
[HttpGet("token")]
public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
{
    return await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
}
```

It works fine. After access token expired I get 401 on the client side, so it would be great to have an opportunity to update access token automatically when it was expired.

According to a documentation I supposed, that It can be reached by setting AllowOfflineAccess to true and adding suitable scope "offline_access".

Maybe I don't understand the right flow of the access and refresh tokens usages. Can I do it automatically or it is impossible? I suppose, that we can use refresh tokens in out queries, but I don't understand how.

I've read a lot of SO answers and github issues but I am still confused. Could you help me to figure out?

Comment: _"I've read a lot of SO answers"_ Maybe you could link to some of them, to avoid anyone flagging this as a duplicate of them, if they didn't help you. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your notice about SO questions, I have found the suitable one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175115/how-to-use-refresh-token-in-identityserver-4

Comment: I have implemented the second approach. My solution include checking the access token expiration time and if it takes less than 1 minute - updating the access token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After investigation and communicating in comments I've found the answer. Before every API call I get the expite time and according to the result update access_token or return existing:

```
[HttpGet("config/accesstoken")]
public async Task<string> GetOrUpdateAccessTokenAsync()
{
    var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    var expiredDate = DateTime.Parse(await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at"), null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);

    if (!((expiredDate - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes < 1))
    {
        return accessToken;
    }

    lock (LockObject)
    {
        if (_expiredAt.HasValue && !((_expiredAt.Value - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes < 1))
        {
            return accessToken;
        }

        var response = DiscoveryClient.GetAsync(_identitySettings.Authority).Result;
        if (response.IsError)
        {
            throw new Exception(response.Error);
        }

        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(response.TokenEndpoint, _identitySettings.Id, _identitySettings.Secret);
        var refreshToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token").Result;

        var tokenResult = tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken).Result;
        if (tokenResult.IsError)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        accessToken = tokenResult.AccessToken;
        var idToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token").Result;

        var tokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>
        {
            new AuthenticationToken
            {
                Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken,
                Value = idToken
            },
            new AuthenticationToken
            {
                Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken,
                Value = accessToken
            },
            new AuthenticationToken
            {
                Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken,
                Value = tokenResult.RefreshToken
            }
        };

        var expiredAt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(tokenResult.ExpiresIn);
        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken
        {
            Name = "expires_at",
            Value = expiredAt.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        });

        var info = HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).Result;
        info.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);
            HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, info.Principal, info.Properties).Wait();

            _expiredAt = expiredAt.ToLocalTime();
        }

        return accessToken;                                                 
    }
}
```

I call this method to get the access_token and add int to the API call headers:

```
private async getAuthenticationHeader(): Promise<any> {
    return axios.get('config/accesstoken').then((response: any) => {
        return { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${response.data}` } };
    });
}

async getAsync<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
    return this.axios
        .get(url, await this.getAuthenticationHeader())
        .then((response: any) => response.data as T)
        .catch((err: Error) => {
            console.error(err);
            throw err;
        });
}
```

Double check locking were implemented to prevent simultamious async API calls try to change access_token at the same time. Optionally you can cashe you access_token into static variable or cache, it is up to you.

If you have any advices or alternatives it would be insteresting to discuss. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways of doing this:

Client side - Handle the authentication and obtaining of the token on the client side using a lib like oidc-client-js. This has a feature that allows automatic renewal of the token via a `prompt=none` call to the `authorize` endpoint behind the scenes.

Refresh token - store this in your existing cookie and then use it to request a new access token as needed. In this mode your client side code doing the AJAX calls would need to be aware of token errors and automatically request a new token from the server whereby `GetAccessTokenAsync()` could use the refresh token to get a new access token.

Comment: I have tried the oidc-client to request a user by the method mgr.getUser. It didn't work, maybe because I didn't call the mgr.signIn method. I just add an [Authorize] attribute to the action which return my view. I'll investigate this one more time with your suggested settings.

Comment: If I use the refresh token I need to know the access token expiration time to avoid unnecessary requests to the IS4 for all calls of the API. I mean that you should know when you need to update the access token. Could you advise the good way to implement this approach?

Comment: To use the oidc-client-js client side library you'd need to configure your IDP to work with that client and perform the sign in process via that library. It's quite a significant shift in app architecture so probably not the best approach for you at this point.

Regarding the refresh token approach - you can either just renew the token the first time an API call fails (i.e. look for the `401` status code and any additional headers like `WWW-Authenticate`). Alternatively you can get the expiry time of the token from the `exp` claim inside the access token and check this before every API call.

Comment: I get expire time before every API call and according to the result update the access token or just return exsiting one. It appeares the better solution for my architecture. I will add the answer to this question. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, feel free to give this answer an upvote ;)