# How to make Owin automatically use refresh token when access token expires

Tags: asp.net, owin, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an Owin client connected to IdentityServer 4, and am wondering how to get owin to request a new access_token using the refresh token. I can successfully get owin to swap the code given for an access_token, id_token and refresh_token with the following configuration:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookie"
            });
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
                ClientId = "mywebsite",
                ClientSecret = "secret",
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:5001/",
                ResponseType = "code",
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                SaveTokens = true,
                UseTokenLifetime = true,
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookie",
                Scope = "openid profile email offline_access",
                RedeemCode = true,
                
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(n);
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    TokenResponseReceived = n =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(n);
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                },
                
            });
        }
```

Firstly, where do I save these tokens to? I can access them all the SecurityTokenValidated callback - should they go into the claims? Database? Memory?

Secondly, I have on my IdentityServer client configuration the access_token lifespan set to 60s, identity_token set to 3600s, and refresh to 30 days (please note the access_token is only this short for testing purposes). So how can I configure Owin to recognize that the access_token has expired and that it needs to go back to identityserver with the refresh_token and get a new one. Answers with example code snippets would be appreciated as my knowledge on all this is very small.

Relevant Info:
IS4 v3
.Net Framework v4.6
Client is set in IS to allow offline access

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? 
I can only find solutions or example for dotnet core apps...

Comment: I had to do it manually. AFAIK Owin won't do any refreshing for you. I had to check the lifetime of my access token before I used it and if it was about to expire or already had, use my refresh token to get a fresh one from IS. Bit of a pain but at least you understand whats going on. Make sure you save tokens for each user somewhere secure and fast to access

Comment: No problem, good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article:

- [Automatic Token Management for ASP.NET Core and Worker Services 1.0](https://leastprivilege.com/2020/05/18/automatic-token-management-for-asp-net-core-and-worker-services-1-0/)

Otherwise than that there is no logic in the AddOpenIdConnect(..) handler to deal with renewal of refresh tokens. I think its up to your application to refresh them. Refreshing them in code is not that hard if you have saved the refresh token somewhere safe.

See this question [How to use 'refresh_token' in IdentityServer 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175115/how-to-use-refresh-token-in-identityserver-4#44240242)

Comment: This seems to be for .Net Core applications. Is this applicable to .Net Framework apps that are using Owin?

Comment: i am not sure  UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication or OWIN handles refresh automatically for you.